# how to append extraa parameters in query string

Tags: php, jquery

```
function myfunction123()
{
    var d1=$('form').serialize();
    d1+="&table=";
    alert(d1);
    return d1;
}
 if isset($_REQUEST['table']){}
```

it will give undefined index table
i used this funtion on the click event of submit button.it will display alert messege like this.

[image]

Comment: is this a demo or a question?

Comment: the table pass in query string.i under stand that there is no value to give table but it will give null value not undefined index table error

Comment: Well you're missing a single quote after table for 1

Comment: please give example of this.

Comment: Hes saying isset($_REQUEST['table]){} should be isset($_REQUEST['table']){}

Comment: However This is Not matter i Perfrom This also Give Undefined Index Table Error

Comment: Check payload or query data send to server in devTools;